# Conditional Formatting vs VBA formatting speed/memory

Tags: vba, performance, excel, conditional-formatting

I'm developing a template spreadsheet that will resize arrays of data when refreshed. Currently I'm using conditional formatting to add borders as the arrays grow and vice-versa.

Is it cleaner to use VBA to format the cells when they're refreshed rather than having the majority of the sheet subject to the conditional formatting rules?  What are the benefits of one vs. the other?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume Array of data means list of rows in worksheet. If you are not allowing your user to edit the worksheet, conditional formatting still good to go. But conditional formatting will go to issue, when some user move around the cells, insert column or copy paste cell that having conditional formatting.

Comment: If and only if, the formatting will only change after your VBA code execute, then for better performance, you should go for VBA formatting. Because conditional formatting are like formula, it going to refresh/calculate when there have changes on worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub fill()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim num As Long

    Randomize

    For i = 1 To 500000
        num = Int(50 * Rnd) + 1
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = num
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = num
    Next
End Sub

Sub format()
    Dim i As Long

    Debug.Print Now
    With Sheet1
        For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value > 20 Then .Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
        Next
    End With
    Debug.Print Now
End Sub

Sub conditionally_format()
    Debug.Print Now

    With Sheet1.Columns(2)
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=40"
        .FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = -16383844
        .FormatConditions(1).Font.TintAndShade = 0
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 13551615
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Debug.Print Now
End Sub
```

On my HP-asaurus, I get the following results

```
format:
7/22/2016 1:10:34 PM
7/22/2016 1:10:49 PM
conditionally_format:
7/22/2016 1:25:06 PM
7/22/2016 1:25:07 PM
```

However, it should be noted that the results for the `conditionally_format` sub represent the time it takes to run that code, not to actually conditionally format the cells. I don't know how to measure that except by changing a value on the spreadsheet and seeing how long it takes. Even doing that, is impossible because it happens so fast that I can't measure it. This means the code to loop through each cell runs *much* slower than setting a conditional format. This really is to be expected since Excel is loading each `Cell` object, then checking the cell objects `.Value` and then setting the `Interior.ColorIndex` property based on that evaluation. The same is done with conditional formatting except VBA stays out of the picture. It is Excel's underlying (and optimized) compiled code performing the actions. Is the speed difference huge? Not really. My slow laptop did half a million comparisons in 15 seconds vs the essentially instantaneous formatting by conditional formatting rules.

Benefits... that's a tougher call. I would think more end users would understand conditional formatting rules, which would also mean more end users can monkey with them. This may not be desirable. Is it cleaner? Tough call again. If you set the formatting rules from the UI, a developer may not think to look for any conditional formatting rules, and since nothing shows up in the IDE about conditional formatting, this again could lead to undesirable consequences. There have been [bugs with conditional formatting](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/conditional-formatting-does-not-update/08fed959-df7a-4e43-a0ae-a2aa5f587edd?db=5&auth=1) in the past, but I do not know if this is still an issue. I would think the method you ultimately choose will come down to how much control you want to give an end user vs. how much code you want to create.